# format y-axis colour bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I a really new to ggplot. I wonder it there is a quick answer to this problem

I have been asked to reproduce graphs with an Y-axis indicating value categories for the data displayed as multi-line plots. The plot in the hyperlink was made manually in a spreadsheet.
I am trying to generate the coloured labels aligned with the y-scale

[original plot & data](http://goo.gl/kGlAiV)
So far I have managed to reproduce the line plots with this code

```
ggplot(p2r_m,aes(x=time,y=value,group=variable,colour=variable)) + 
geom_line() +                                 
geom_point( size=4,shape=21,fill="white")
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a reproducible version of your data i.e `dput(p2r_m)`. SO users should not need to log in to google docs to access a spreadsheet and then coerce it into the long format you have (presumable created using `melt`) too many assumptions and too much work given you want code for free.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possibility - you can make labels with `geom_text` and have some colour with `geom_rect` wherever you like. If we make a dataframe with the required data:

```
labels <- data.frame(id = c("Very poor", "Poor", "Moderate", "Good", "Very good"), 
  min = seq(0, 80, 20), max = seq(20, 100, 20))
```

You then need to move your `x` and `y` mapping to each `geom` (or at least I don't know of a way of avoiding this):

```
base <- ggplot(p2r.m) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=time,y=value,group=variable,colour=variable))  +
  geom_point(aes(x=time,y=value), size=4,shape=21,fill="white")
```

And then reference the label data:

```
base + geom_rect(data = labels, aes(ymin = min, ymax = max,xmin = 0, xmax = 0.5, fill = id)) + 
    geom_text(data = labels, aes(x = 0.25, y = (min + max)/2, label = id), angle = 90) + 
    guides(fill = F)
```

[image]

By the way, your data doesn't seem to match the plot you posted.